# Why doesn't voltage drop naturally as a charge moves through the circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential-energy, voltage

If we ignore circuits for a moment and just think about a fixed charge and a test charge in space, we know that if we release the test charge, its PE changes and KE changes such that PE + KE is constant. However, in a circuit, we never talk about voltage dropping because a charge is converting PE to KE; we only talk about voltage dropping because a charge goes through a load. Why is this? Does voltage drop when a charge moves at all?

Answer (score 0):

Because we are using the approximation of an ideal conductor.
Within an ideal conductor, the electric field is zero; particles rearrange in a perfect manner to cancel out the electric field.

When there is no field, there is no change in the kinetic energy of particles - thus, there is no change in the potential energy either.

Comment: “Within an ideal conductor, the electric field is zero”. Then what causes the current? If there is no electric field shouldn’t the charges just stay put?

Comment: The electric field accelerates the charges. It is not needed for a constant kinetic energy; in the classical model, the current sees the whole circuit before deciding on how much it moves. There's a great question on that on the electric engineering stack exchange, something along the line of "how does the current know how much to move".